# ORDER BY on 2 levels

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got the simple SQL request:

```
SELECT campagne, sujet, id FROM campagne ORDER BY id DESC
```

who returns that:

```
campagne        sujet   id
campagne1(009)  sujet1  5910
campagne1(008)  sujet1  5909
campagne1(007)  sujet1  5908
campagne1(006)  sujet1  5907
campagne1(005)  sujet1  5906
campagne1(004)  sujet1  5905
campagne1(003)  sujet1  5904
campagne1(002)  sujet1  5903
campagne1(001)  sujet1  5902
campagne2(009)  sujet2  5901
campagne2(008)  sujet2  5900
campagne2(007)  sujet2  5899
campagne2(006)  sujet2  5898
campagne2(005)  sujet2  5897
campagne2(004)  sujet2  5896
campagne2(003)  sujet2  5895
campagne2(002)  sujet2  5894
campagne2(001)  sujet2  5893
campagne3(009)  sujet3  5892
campagne3(008)  sujet3  5891
campagne3(007)  sujet3  5890
campagne3(006)  sujet3  5889
campagne3(005)  sujet3  5888
campagne3(004)  sujet3  5887
campagne3(003)  sujet3  5886
campagne3(002)  sujet3  5885
campagne3(001)  sujet3  5884
```

And I want return that:

```
campagne        sujet   id
campagne1(001)  sujet1  5902
campagne1(002)  sujet1  5903
campagne1(003)  sujet1  5904
campagne1(004)  sujet1  5905
campagne1(005)  sujet1  5906
campagne1(006)  sujet1  5907
campagne1(007)  sujet1  5908
campagne1(008)  sujet1  5909
campagne1(009)  sujet1  5910
campagne2(001)  sujet2  5893
campagne2(002)  sujet2  5894
campagne2(003)  sujet2  5895
campagne2(004)  sujet2  5896
campagne2(005)  sujet2  5897
campagne2(006)  sujet2  5898
campagne2(007)  sujet2  5899
campagne2(008)  sujet2  5900
campagne2(009)  sujet2  5901
campagne3(001)  sujet3  5884
campagne3(002)  sujet3  5885
campagne3(003)  sujet3  5886
campagne3(004)  sujet3  5887
campagne3(005)  sujet3  5888
campagne3(006)  sujet3  5889
campagne3(007)  sujet3  5890
campagne3(008)  sujet3  5891
campagne3(009)  sujet3  5892
```

So for each group of sujet, I need to order the campagnes ASC (or by id DESC)...

What SQL request can do the job ?
Big thanks for help !

Comment: `order by sujet, campagnes`

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiple sort keys:

```
SELECT campagne, sujet, id
FROM campagne
ORDER BY sujet, campagne
```

Comment: Yes but actually, the order by id DESC allow to print the campagne by the youngest to the oldest. It is not the case without.

Comment: Well you show a data output and that isnt `order by id DESC` maybe you should rewrite that.

Comment: It is order by id DESC. (5910 to 5884)

Comment: @Macbernie: you said in your question, and I quote: `I need to order the campagnes ASC (or by id DESC)`. That's exactly what I did, order the campagnes ASC. If that's not correct than feel free to modify as you wish of course. Now you know how to sort by multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to order on two columns with different hierarchies.
So you could go for

```
ORDER BY campagne ASC, id DESC;
```

I guess this is what you meant, right?

For reference see: [PostgreSQL-Tutorial ORDER BY](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-order-by/)